# Is there an option to parse a Dict of list of dicts in flask for setting up a bootstrap dashboard?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have json_data which looks like this:

```
{
  "table_data": [
    {
      "id": 1004,
      "summary": "a",
      "type": "b",
      "date": "2019-08-08 08:08:03",
      "name": "c"
      "unwanted_var": d
    }
    {
      "id": 1005,
      "summary": "e",
      "type": "f",
      "date": "2019-08-08 08:09:03",
      "name": "g"
      "unwanted_var": h
    }
    {
      "id": 1006,
      "summary": "j",
      "type": "k",
      "date": "2019-08-08 08:08:03",
      "name": "l"
      "unwanted_var": m
    }
  ],
  "alert_data": [
    {
      "id": 1005,
      "summary": "x",
      "type": "y",
      "date": "2019-08-01 08:08:03",
      "entity": "z",
      "md5": "873817382hshbhdbc",
    }
  ]
}
```

I am using render_template in flask to render a table that would display the values of **table_data** with 4 columns for a bootstrap table corresponding to these rows:

```
                      | ID | Summary | Type | Name |
```

I have tried using a few for loops but that isnt working:

```
                {% for item in json_data['table_data'] %}
                <tr>
                  <td>{{ item['table_data']['summary'] }}</td>
                  <td>{{ item['table_data']['type'] }}</td>
                  <td>{{ item['table_data']['env'] }}</td>
                  <td>{{ item['table_data']['state'] }}</td>
                  <td>{{ item['table_data']['entity'] }}</td>
                  <td>{{ item['table_data']['autohealing'] }}</td>
                  <td>{{ item['table_data']['resolved'] }}</td>
                  <td>{{ item['table_data']['time'] }}</td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
```

```
                {% for item in json_data %}
                <tr>
                {% for key[table_data] in item %}
                <td>{{ table_data[value] }}</td>
                {% endfor %}
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
```

The goal would be to get a table like this:

```
                      | ID   | Summary | Type | Name |
                      | 1004 |    a    |   b  |   c  |
                      | 1005 |    e    |   f  |   l  |
                      | 1006 |    j    |   k  |   h  |
```

Any pointers would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
{% for item in json_data['table_data'] %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ item['summary'] }}</td>
      <td>{{ item['type'] }}</td>
      <td>{{ item['env'] }}</td>
      <td>{{ item['state'] }}</td>
      <td>{{ item['entity'] }}</td>
      <td>{{ item['autohealing'] }}</td>
      <td>{{ item['resolved'] }}</td>
      <td>{{ item['time'] }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Maybe I am still missing the correct way to load the data in the tables using js? I seem to be getting the correct result in python flask when I print it, but in the HTML, I think the data is not being loaded correctly.

Answer (score 0):

`import json
import requests
data=requests.json
for item in data['table_data']:
    print("variable_name" =item[keys])`

## just for reference, put your key here, to access corresponding value.